# How to unselect a previously set selection using RangeBuilder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

How to unselect a previously set selection using the below code?

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var rangeBuilder = doc.newRange();
rangeBuilder.addElement(body.editAsText(), 0, body.editAsText().getText().length - 1);
doc.setSelection(rangeBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been googling and looking around the community for quite some time, but I wasn't able to find any direct function to remove the text selection of the document. So as a workaround, what I did is this:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var rangeBuilder = doc.newRange();
  rangeBuilder.addElement(body.editAsText(), 0, body.editAsText().getText().length - 1);
  doc.setSelection(rangeBuilder.build());
  
  var rangeBuilder2 = doc.newRange();
  var text = body.editAsText().appendText(" ");
  rangeBuilder2.addElement(text, body.editAsText().getText().length - 1, body.editAsText().getText().length - 1);
  doc.setSelection(rangeBuilder2.build());
  text.deleteText(body.editAsText().getText().length - 1, body.editAsText().getText().length - 1);
```

I just appended a blank space to the body, had the new `RangeBuilder` add it as its element, and set the selection of the doc to it. Afterwards, I just deleted the text. It's just a simple workaround, you can tweak around it to whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thank you, Ok sure works, but how do I correct here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689758/selection-and-iteration-through-cursor